# Deploying Symfony 1.4 project

Tags: php, symfony1

I have recently developed a project which is written using Symfony 1.4 which I installed through PEAR. In previous Symfony versions there used to be **freeze** and **unfreeze** functions to copy all the necessary files, but in this versions these functions are missing. So my question is - what is the fastest way to deploy my project on a shared hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php* change the require_once statement for *sfCoreAutoload* class. Make it search for symfony in *lib/vendor/symfony*:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

Now you can do two things:

- Copy whole symfony lib into *lib/vendor/symfony* dir. This way you always have symfony with your project. Drawback is you have to copy it while sending files to the server.
- Create *lib/vendor/symfony* symbolic link pointing to your symfony lib. Advantage is you don't have to copy whole framework all the time. Drawback is you still have to put symfony in the same location on dev and production servers. However, symbolic link might be relative to the project (i.e. one level up).

Comment: You may also need to enable mod_rewrite in .htaccess , depending on your provider.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try this.

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosting is always a pain with Symfony. I haven't attempted it myself. But what you can do is just copy the lib folder from your symfony installation into your project lib folder and just point your projectConfiguration.php to where you put the symfony libs in your project.

This just does the same thing as the freeze but manually.

Answer (score 0):

@kuba, your statement in config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php has one 'lib' too many. It should be:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/vendor/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```